# pyspark how to read csv with a header to enforce a schema with select columns

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, header, schema

I have a requirement to read from a csv with a header as columns, also I want to enforce the schema.

for example the source csv is as

| id | name | dob | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Smith | 2000-01-01 | Male |
| 2 | John | 2000-02-01 | Male |

I only want to select column 2,3 and want to specify the schema as
name: string
dob: date

what I've tried is with the header=true option and schema like below:

```
schema = StructType([
                    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
                    StructField('dob', DateType(), True)
                ])

df = spark.read.csv("somefile.csv", schema=schema, header=True)
```

but it doesn't work as expected.

1. with schema and header=True, it will read the first column as id and second column as dob but try to convert it into Date then with null value

| id | dob |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |

2. with just header=True, it is able to read the whole csv but it contains some columns I don't want and also all columns are string type.

I prefer to get the schema during the read but it seems no way to archive it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your data has columns in order `id, name, dob` and it is read in that order (irrespective of header names) and the values are casted/parsed to type provided in schema.

You can read from first three columns and choose to drop "id" column from dataframe:

```py
schema = "id int, name string, dob date"

df = spark.read \
          .option("header", True) \
          .csv("/content/sample_data/test.csv", schema=schema) \
          .drop("id")

df.show()

+-----+----------+
| name|       dob|
+-----+----------+
|Smith|2000-01-01|
| John|2000-02-01|
+-----+----------+


df.printSchema()

root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dob: date (nullable = true)
```